# Inconsistencies in a mongodb collection that has no documents but when I do a count(), it tells me that I have 15

Tags: mongodb

When I run this command: db.collection.find({}) in the mongosh, I get no documents, however when I run db.collection.find({}).count(), it tells me I have 15 documents. The same thing happens when I do a db.collection.stats(), which returns in the count: 15. Could someone explain me why this happens, how I could solve it and things to consider about this problem in a production environment ?

Comment: It is unlikely that the results with find and count can be wrong. What version of MongoDB are you using and from what tool? Are you sure you are working with the same collection? If you are looking to count documents use the `db.collection.countDocuments()` - this gives exact count of the documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#inaccurate-counts-without-query-predicate) state, the `count` method on a cursor or a collection without a query return a count that is based on metadata:

> When you call  count()  on a find() operation which does not specify a
> query predicate, the  count()  method can return inaccurate document
> counts. These  count()  methods return results based on the
> collection's metadata, which may result in an approximate count.

Therefore, these methods have been deprecated; `countDocuments` or `estimatedDocumentCount` should be used instead.

Comment: Okay. I ask because it happens on Mongodb Compass, when I open the collection I get 15 documents at the top of the application. I understand that it is an implementation error of the count in Compass. that instead of doing a real count, it uses estimatedDocumentCount to return that data. Thanks for your answer